# Ruby Loop Countdown method not Counting down

Tags: ruby, loops, methods

I'm trying to define a method that countdowns 10 to 0 and at the end returns HAPPY NEW YEARS! however i don't want i"am doing wrong?

```
def countdown(number)
  while number > 0
    puts "#{number} SECONDS(S)!"
    number -= 1
  end
 "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
end
```

Comment: You intend to subtract `11` at each step? Probably that's it. If you need to ask in future, it is often good to add the actual vs expected output to your question, to make that sort of thing clear (it's perfectly OK for a script to count down 11 at a time, if that's what you want! Just that seems unusual.)

Comment: sorry i shouldved check before i hit submit thats suppose to be -= 1

Comment: @Daquon: In that case you need to explain more about what is going wrong, because your code apparently works (or at least it matches your written description). Add 1) How you are calling it. 2) What happens. 3) What you wanted/expected to happen

Comment: @NeilSlater its suppose to countdown from 10 using the string interpolation at the end saying happy new years

Comment: @NeilSlater its should display to the console 10 seconds - 0 seconds then display happy new year

Comment: So, to clarify your problem is 1) It doesn't display the "0 SECONDS(S)!" line 2) It doesn't display "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"?

Comment: I loaded your code into an interactive ruby session and It worked for me.  I  am not sure what your problem is.  The code displays 10-1 SECOND(S)! then it returns "HAPPY NEW YEAR!".  If this is the functionality you wanted it is working.  However if you wanted it to display happy new year as well then you need to put puts infront of that.

Comment: This is not idiomatic ruby code. Ruby programmers rarely use ``while``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def countdown(number)
  while number > 0
    puts "#{number} SECONDS(S)!"
    number -= 1
  end
 puts "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"
end
```

I added a puts on the last line of your code. You method is counting down to 0 seconds, but the last line only return the string "HAPPY NEW YEAR!", and does not print it to the screen. Or if you need to return the string and print it on the screen, you can do `p "HAPPY NEW YEAR!"`

Comment: However the assignment requirements me to use the while loop that's why i'm having so much trouble

Comment: its suppose to be a new years countdown

Comment: if that's the case, you just need to put a 'puts' or 'p' before the happy new year string.

Comment: @Daquon just put `sleep 1` before `number -=1` and your code will do a countdown.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search revealed that you are apparently trying to solve https://learn.co/lessons/countdown-to-midnight (you really should have included that link)

Your code is not passing the [spec](https://github.com/learn-co-curriculum/countdown-to-midnight/blob/master/spec/countdown_spec.rb), because it contains an additional `S`:

```
puts "#{number} SECONDS(S)!"
#                     ^
```

It has to be:

```
puts "#{number} SECOND(S)!"
```

Comment: i solve the problem already thank you

Comment: however i'am having trouble with the second part of that countdown_to_sleep if you can offer a hand with that ? i'm having trouble trying to understand the sleep function

Comment: @Daquon please post a new question and include the relevant details.

Comment: i can apparently i ask bad questions so i have to wait three days

Comment: @Daquon, you can always "fix" any current question.